# Int32.Parse() returns 0x0001 when 0 is expected - why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am using Int32.Parse() to convert the value of a DropDownList; however the returned value after conversion is:

> 0x0001

instead of the expected `0`.

My code is:

```
myObject.Id = Int32.Parse(ddlName.SelectedValue);
```

The selected value is "0" in this case. Why does it return a '0x0001' instead of a 0? What is happening and is that a memory register address?

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing SelectedValue and SelectedIndex?

Comment: You have something wrong here. That's not what Int32.Parse() does. Step through it in the debugger and look at the value being passed in. Something is surely not what you're assuming it is.

Comment: Thanks for the post edit CodeKaizen. I got an answer immediated from Madhur. It was the debug 'Hex' problem.

Comment: Jonathan, it was the Hex option on debug. Unchecking it fiexed the problem. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you checking through debug Window ?

Check if you have enabled Viewing as Hex in Visual studio watch.

Comment: Yep I am checking through debug window.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that he is concerned about the hex representation as much as it is the wrong integer value.

Comment: Thanks Madhur I pressed Hex on debug accidently. Uncheking Hex fixed the problem.

Comment: Great to know, And I got a downvote for fixing your problem :)

Comment: @Madhur Ahuja: Nice answer, and LOL for you got a down-vote. +1 to comfort you.

Comment: That's fine man, I am not blaming anybody .. these are part of the SO game :)

Answer (score 2):

`int.Parse(string s)` uses the default `CultureInfo`, however I'm absolutely sure "0" can't be parsed to 0x0001 in any of the cultures(I looped all the cultures and see if "0" will be parsed to other values contains "0x"). So somewhere else is wrong. I think you'd better check:

```
(1) string s = ddlName.SelectedValue.ToString();  //make sure s is "0"
(2) int num = int.Parse(s);  //check if num is 0 or not
(3) myObject.Id = num;   //check the type of myObject.Id(supposed an int/long)
(4) Check the "set" method of myObject.Id (if there is one)
```

Comment: I agree. @ Damien - I am sure there is something else wrong too. 0x0001 is not equal to 0 in hex.

Comment: Thanks for your response danny. It was the Hex option in debug options that was causing the problem. But you did cleared my confusion about conversion.